# Need to switch SKScenes at applicationWillResignActive

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I need to switch to my pause scene when I get applicationWillResignActive so the user cannot browse the background app screens without my timer running. I use the following code, but the switch to my pause scene doesn't happen until after I bring the app back into the foreground. What am I doing wrong?

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if let liveWindow = window {
        if let viewController = liveWindow.rootViewController {
            if let rotopathViewController = viewController as? RotopathViewController {
                rotopathViewController.pause()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My view controller's pause function is simple.

```
func pause() {
    game.score.pause()
    rotopathView.presentScene(pausedScene)
}
```

and it just calls

```
func pause() {
    elapsedTime += Int(round(Date().timeIntervalSince(intervalStartTime)))
    isActive = false
}
```

If I move some code around and make sure that I set isActive = false after the presentScene call, there is no difference. Also, if I remove the isActive = false assignment, there is no difference.

Comment: You can add a notification observer directly on your scene

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-detect-when-your-app-moves-to-the-background

Comment: Using the direct notification worked. Knight0fDragon: Can you add an answer with your comment so that I can accept it?

Comment: Also, if anyone knows why the notification works and the implementation of applicationWillResignActive doesn't, I'd like to know still. Thanks.

Comment: Well you shouldnt be getting the view the way you are doing it

Comment: at some point I am going to say that the view you are grabbing is not the view you are on, so pause is failing.

Comment: Thanks again, Knight0fDragon. Will you add an answer instead of a comment so that I can accept it?